# Is it possible for a DLL to open explorer?

Tags: c++, dll, game-maker-studio-2

Im trying to make (what I thought was a simple) extension for Game maker studio 2.

I am restricted to making a DLL app.

I am wondering is there any was to have a dll app open the file explorer have the user locate a file and then return said directory?

I fell like this is a sumb question but one I really need to know the answer too before slaving away coding for hours only to find its not possible.

Comment: The answer is yes, and also, there is no such thing as a DLL app.

Comment: Sorry Yes that should be file. Thanks for the info. I shall now delve into coding and getting it working!

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to launch the explorer but to open a file dialog that allows the user to select a file.

Depending on the framework you use in your program the solutions may differ.

If you are using Qt framework you may use a `QFileDialog` for a platform independent mechanism.

If you are okay that it will only works on Windows then you may directly use the WinAPI functions [`GetOpenFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea)  or [`GetSaveFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getsavefilenamea) (that is a lot easier than the [Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776913(v=vs.85)) that is suggested as replacement on their documentation pages)

Answer (score 0):

On GameMaker terms, you want to use get_open_filename or get_open_filename_ext.

See Dialog Module ([marketplace](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/6621/dialog-module), [github](https://github.com/time-killer-games/DialogModule/)) for C++ implementation reference.